# How to add letter "T" between date and time using Oracle?

Tags: datetime, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to add letter T between date and time using oracle

Like this:

```
2015/01/01T00:00:00
```

Script for date

```
to_char(l.date_generated, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref416):

> You can include these characters in a date format model: ...Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks

so,

```
TO_CHAR(l.date_generated, 'yyyy/mm/dd"T"hh24:mi:ss')
```