# ORA-01821: date format not recognized error for ISO 8601 date with local time

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to convert the date in SQL based on the parameter value in my Java code. However when the below query is executed I am getting error . Request you to help me in fixing this query.

```
 SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-08-26T05:46:30.488+0100',
 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss.sTZH:TZM')
  FROM DUAL
  *
Error at line 2
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

Date and Time format info:

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: The `"` in the actual timestamp value are invalid. You need to use `'2015-08-26T05:46:30.488+0100'`

Comment: I have removed the " in time stamp now. It is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two issues: `TO_DATE` doesn't recognise any time zone components or fractional seconds, you'll have to convert it to timestamp with time zone, and `.s` isn't how you represent fractional seconds anyway, you need `.ff`. The valid format models [are shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3).

Putting those together you can do:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('2015-08-26T05:46:30.488+0100',
 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss.ffTZHTZM')
FROM DUAL;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2015-08-26T05:46:30.488+0100','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZ
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
26-AUG-15 05.46.30.488000000 +01:00
```

If you really want it as a date you'll need to decide what to do with the time zone information - either assume it's local time (essentially ignore it), or convert to UTC or some other time zone. You may really want to keep it as a timestamp with time zone though.

Comment: Even better to match the format exactly and not rely on Oracle's guessing right. That is, the format model should follow the structure of the string literal; the format model should end with `...ff+TZHTZM` (the + should be there explicitly in the model if it's in the literal argument, and there should be no : between THZ and TZM in the model if there's no : between them in the literal). In this case Oracle guessed right, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @mathguy - agree with you on the colon, I hadn't noticed that. Not so sure about the + sign; I didn't know that was allowed (the docs don't seem to mention it), and TZH can be positive or negative anyway so I believe it's implied already and is redundant - Oracle isn't having to guess that. I'd also personally find it slightly confusing as at best it's indicating that character can be + or - (but then I have the same issue with AM/PM in a format model, so maybe that's just me!). And it would be wrong to include it explicitly in a `to_char()` call. But it's certainly worth mentioning, thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think you are absolutely right about the +/-, I got carried away. That is part of TZH, it wasn't a verbatim token...   :)

Comment: Just in case someone else is wondering what is the role of the "T" (the T letter sorrounded by quotatioon marks) part in the `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZ` example: it is just a literal, not a special character - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146645/how-to-add-letter-t-between-date-and-time-using-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is pretty specific. Oracle does not recognize the given date format `YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss.sTZH:TZM`.

You can refer to this page in order to build a proper date format: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php