# How do I compare the current timestamp converted to UTC to another timestamp converted to UTC on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pull rows from an oracle SQL table that are 30 minutes or less from a specific time.  However the time is not stored as a date field, it is stored in a VARCHAR2 field in this format "2019-04-04T21:32:38+0000"

Is there a way to do this in a SQL query?

Tried taking the time and converting it but I can only get timestamps and I don't know how to offset the time correctly

Comment: please add some example data and expected result

Comment: Do you mean [converting that column string value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39165392/266304), or converting/adjusting the time you want to compare against? (And why is it stored as a string instead of a more suitable data type?)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll need to do is convert your string to a datetime type. Since your string has a timezone value, this will convert it to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type.

```
to_timestamp_tz( '2019-04-04T21:32:38+0000', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:sstzhtzm')
```

That gives me "04-APR-19 09.32.38.000000000 PM GMT" and it's a date/time value, not a character value.

You say you're comparing this to some other value, but give no details, so I can't really go any further.

Also, try not to store date/times as `varchar2s`. It will only cause problems.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately I don't really have control over the timestamp format that they're sending.

What I'm comparing to is the current time.  I wasn't sure how to convert the current time into a TZ and how to compare it to that value that you mentioned.

Comment: @iscariotTF - `systimestamp` and `current_timestamp` both already have time zone information, so you can compare those with the  result of the `to_timestamp_tz(...)` call directly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to UTC. As @eaolson showed you can convert the string you have to a timestamp with time zone value. You can then compare that directly with any other timestamp with time zone value - Oracle will handle any adjustments invisibly. You can convert to UTC of course, but you don't need to.

> I wasn't sure how to convert the current time into a TZ

`systimestamp` and `current_timestamp` both already have time zone information.

So, to demonstrate with some queries run close together for consistency:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1 TZR';

select current_timestamp, current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT' as now_as_gmt
from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                   NOW_AS_GMT               
----------------------------------- -------------------------
2019-04-15 16:02:29.6 EUROPE/LONDON 2019-04-15 15:02:29.6 GMT
```

and using a CTE to generate some data just before and after your 30-minute cut-off:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (some_time) as (
  select '2019-04-04T21:32:38+0000' from dual
  union all
  select to_char(current_timestamp at time zone 'Africa/Nairobi'
    - interval '30' minute, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') from dual
  union all
  select to_char(current_timestamp at time zone 'Europe/London'
    - interval '29' minute, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') from dual
  union all
  select to_char(current_timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York'
    - interval '28' minute, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') from dual
  union all
  select to_char(current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
    - interval '27' minute, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') from dual
)
-- query
select some_time,
  to_timestamp_tz(some_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') some_time_as_tstz,
  to_timestamp_tz(some_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') at time zone 'GMT' some_time_as_gmt
from your_table;

SOME_TIME                SOME_TIME_AS_TSTZ            SOME_TIME_AS_GMT         
------------------------ ---------------------------- -------------------------
2019-04-04T21:32:38+0000 2019-04-04 21:32:38.0 GMT    2019-04-04 21:32:38.0 GMT
2019-04-15T17:32:29+0300 2019-04-15 17:32:29.0 +03:00 2019-04-15 14:32:29.0 GMT
2019-04-15T15:33:29+0100 2019-04-15 15:33:29.0 +01:00 2019-04-15 14:33:29.0 GMT
2019-04-15T10:34:29-0400 2019-04-15 10:34:29.0 -04:00 2019-04-15 14:34:29.0 GMT
2019-04-15T14:35:29+0000 2019-04-15 14:35:29.0 GMT    2019-04-15 14:35:29.0 GMT
```

you can see the actual values of the strings converted to timestamps and their GMT equivalents - again,not needed, just for visual verification.

Then you can use `current_timestamp` or `systimestamp` in a filter, adjusting that back 30 minutes:

```
-- same CTE omitted
select some_time,
  to_timestamp_tz(some_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') some_time_as_tstz,
  to_timestamp_tz(some_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM') at time zone 'GMT' some_time_as_gmt
from your_table
where to_timestamp_tz(some_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZHTZM')
  > current_timestamp - interval '30' minute;

SOME_TIME                SOME_TIME_AS_TSTZ            SOME_TIME_AS_GMT         
------------------------ ---------------------------- -------------------------
2019-04-15T15:33:29+0100 2019-04-15 15:33:29.0 +01:00 2019-04-15 14:33:29.0 GMT
2019-04-15T10:34:29-0400 2019-04-15 10:34:29.0 -04:00 2019-04-15 14:34:29.0 GMT
2019-04-15T14:35:29+0000 2019-04-15 14:35:29.0 GMT    2019-04-15 14:35:29.0 GMT
```

The two CTE rows with data 30 minutes or more in the past are excluded. Their actual time zones, or the time zone of your session/system, are honoured in the comparison without having to explicitly convert anything to any specific time zone.

> when they are 30 minutes ahead or less than the current timestamp

Then check your value against a time range:

```
where initial_proc_etr >= current_timestamp - interval '30' minute;
and initial_proc_etr < current_timestamp + interval '30' minute
```

assuming that column has a time zone component, as you said in comments.

Comment: I've just noticed that the questions says "30 minutes or less"; I've done "less than 30 minutes". If you do want the former, just change `>` to `>=` when comparing.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wasn't aware you could do that with timestamps.  I had another question.  There's another table I'm working on with a timestamp field in it, how would I do a select to get only the values in the table where that timestamp field is 5 minutes older than the current time?  As in, if the timestamp was for 7:55 EDT, I'd want to pull it in any time AFTER 7:55EDT?

Comment: @iscariotTF - those times are the same... but same thing, with `your_column > current_timestamp - interval '5' minute`. (If the column is a plain timestamp, not a timestamp with time zone, then you'll need to declare which zone it is nominally in; or make sure the current/sys time is in or adjusted to that nominal column zone. If it does have a time zone already then it'll be fine as it is.)

Comment: Ok..I tried the prescribed solution and I'm getting stuff back that is larger...I'm using the following:

WHERE INITIAL_PROC_ETR IS NOT NULL 
AND PROC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
--AND UPDATE_MSG_SENT = 'N'
AND INITIAL_PROC_ETR > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE--;
ORDER BY BPO_IKS_INFO.RECORD_ID DESC;

This will return values where the INITIAL_PROC_ETR is sometimes more than 4 hours ahead of the current timestamp.

The INITIAL_PROC_ETR field as a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE field.

Comment: Well, yes, that still matches your filters. You don't have an *upper* bound on the date column.

Comment: Ok.  So what I'm wanting is to have the elements be available when they are 30 minutes ahead or less than the current timestamp.  These get processed and flagged so they won't be returned(That update_msg_sent value gets changed)